# Regular expression which only validates if string has value?

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which will only validate if the string has a value.

I've come up with this pattern:

```
pattern: '^$|([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)'
```

The logic is that ^$ - should match empty string , and | is OR.

So in English is empty string OR rest of pattern.

Meaning if the string is empty the regex should return true as matched, but it is not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just check whether the string is empty before running the reg ex?

Comment: already doing that, but it's part of a validation framework based on rules. So not as easy as writing custom code.

Comment: Which language is it?  It'd work if the language supports ERE or PCRE.

Comment: In which language you are using these regular expression ? Check what is the escape character in that language.

Comment: Some systems, for example oracle, consider the empty string as null.  In those cases all comparison with it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
^(?:.*([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?).*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This can depend on what language you are using. `\A` matches the beginning of a string, and `\Z` matches the end of a string.

```
(\A\Z)|([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)
```

Short Java example

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\A\\Z)|([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)");
        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "s";
        String str3 = "abcdababab3";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
        if(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println("True:" + matcher.group());

        }
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str2);
        if(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println("True:" + matcher.group());

        }
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str3);
        if(matcher.find()){
                System.out.println("True:" + matcher.group());

        }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
True:
True:abcdababab3
```

It matched the empty string and `abcdabab3`, but not the `s`